# Biden Got Out ‘Over His Skis,’ Says Obama

Tags: phrases, expressions

I read that headline in the New York Times. From the context, I understood that it means that Biden was a little too hasty. I would like to know the origins of this expression

Comment: I've never heard of this expression, but from its literal meaning, I surmise that when you are in a hurry, you tend to fall over your skis, so by extension, it would mean getting ahead of yourself too soon, or too hasty as you guessed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to ski fast like a [downhill racer](http://www.time.com/time/photoessays/10questions/0,30255,1699743_1511901,00.html), you point your skis downhill and get over your skis, positioning your weight forward.

Similarly, when you [ski jump](http://visual.merriam-webster.com/sports-games/winter-sports/ski-jumping/ski-jumper.php), you get out over your skis to control your descent.

In either case, the connotation is that Vice-President Biden got to a position much more quickly than President Obama would have liked him to, before President Obama was quite ready to declare his position on the matter.

Comment: Plus, if you lean _too_ far out [over your skis](http://books.google.com/books?id=uUE3VHG6rRAC&pg=PA102&dq=%22out+over+his+skis%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=TBGyT43uIYGutwfzq8DdCA&ved=0CD4Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22out%20over%20his%20skis%22&f=false), you're likely to fall on your face.

Comment: I wondered about this expression - over your skis is normally where you want to be! If your weight isn't over your skis you fall over.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen it as, "he got too far out over his skis" (and crashed), which I take to mean he overextended himself; he promised more than he could deliver; he didn't measure up to his expectations; he had more balls than sense.

Answer (score -2):

I am not sure if I was the originator of the phase but in a conversation 25 years or so ago with a coworker I was expressing the feeling I had of not being in control as a skier is when he is leaning too far forward and feels a lack of balance and control and knows he is about to lose all control and crash.

Now I again am not sure if others have used this expression before but since that conversation I and my friend/co-worker have used it repeatedly to convey the feeling of losing control. I believe we were the originators of that phase.

Comment: Please don't shout and the word is *phrase*